# send JavaScript object with unknown properties to asp.net MVC controller

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I have read quite some blogs and stackoverflow answers on how to send a JavaScript object to an asp.net MVC controller. But all examples I have seen so far require you to know which properties the JavaScript object will have (because they all convert the JavaScript object to a C# object).

When I was using PageMethods in asp.net webforms I could send any complex JavaScript object or array (even hierarchical data) and it would be converted to a Dictionary which I could iterate. Any chance I can do something similar in asp.net MVC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I now found a way which works for me.

1. I am converting my data to json and receive it as a string in my ASP.net MVC controller.
2. Then I use the [json.net](http://json.codeplex.com/) library to read the data - since this library allows me to read the data without converting it to a C# (or VB) object.

JavaScript code:

```
//first include the json2 library for older browsers and jQuery
$.post(url, {json: JSON.stringify(mydata)});
```

Server side code:

```
public void xyz(string json)
{
    JObject j = JObject.Parse(json);
    string name = (string)j.SelectToken("Products[0].Name");
    //...
}
```

The good thing: it is "normal" json which means it is not some uncommon format or interface-type.

**EDIT:** I found out that I don't even need the C# json-library if I am using .net 4 - since I can convert any json string to a Dictionary with the help of the JavaScriptSerializer:

```
JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
Dictionary<string, object> data = (Dictionary<string, object>) jss.Deserialize<dynamic>(json_string);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will be converted to a dictionary:

```
[{"key":0, "value":"something"},{"key":2, "value":"something else"},]
```

Obviously, you could do string,string or int, bool or etc...

For example, I have a method like this:

```
public int CollabSortFolder(int FolderId, Dictionary<int, int> Items)
```

I would call is using a GET:

```
/CollabSortFolder?FolderId=111111&Items=[{"Key":3685,"Value":0},{"Key":3670,"Value":1},{"Key":3687,"Value":2}]
```

Now as a GET it's not very elegant, but a post would work the same way.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not working in my example - my parameter is always null. Could you tell me how the serverside controller action would look like. (which parameter?)

Comment: It's still not working for me (even your example code). Items is always null or just empty. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I am using asp.net MVC 3.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is use jQuery plugin toDictionary, this plugin will transform your object to dictionary that asp.net MVC default model binder can understand

e.g.

```
 $.ajax({
    url: "/SomeURL",
    type: "POST",
    data: $.toDictionary(dataToSend)
   });
```

Remember dataToSend is your object

Comment: link to this http://erraticdev.blogspot.com/2010/12/sending-complex-json-objects-to-aspnet.html

Comment: Looks promising - but I'm not sure if it provides what I need, since I can't get it to work. I don't know what type to use for the parameter in the mvc controller. In the blog example he is only showing it with "predefined classes" (Person and Car) but I don't have such server-side classes since I don't know which properties the JavaScript object is going to have.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `Request.Forms` dictionary?

```
public ActionResult MyAction(FormCollection formValues)
{
}
```

Iterate over `formValues`

Comment: Yes, I tried that. But I found it very inconvenient when I have hierarchical data (which I have). Since everything will be a flat list.